# Is it possible to access via ssh a one click app from the Google Cloud Platform marketplace?

Tags: wordpress, ssh, ftp, google-cloud-platform

I just recently installed a one click application from the Google Cloud Platform. I installed WordPress as a VM instance , but when I try to access my VM instance via ssh i see that its empty and it doesn't contain any WordPress files. Is there a way to access the WordPress files either via FTP or even better ssh?

Answer (score 0):

One click deployments should come with everything you need “out of the box”.

You can visit your [Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/) and click on the Word Press resource to view login options and choose SSH or login to the Word Press admin console from there.

[Accessing files through SCP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#scp) can be done through the GCloud command line as well as another alternative.